# Обновление базы данных с сайта ANDROID

Tags: android, sqlite

Каким образом можно получить данные (файл) c сайта для последующего внесения или обновления базы данных самого приложения и возможно ли это?

Comment: Уточните. Вы получается данные с сайта к примеру в формате gson. Дальше вы хотите это добавить эти данные в свою бд? В каком виде? Какая структура? Если у вас она есть, то да вы просто заполняете таблицу своими полями и можете спокойно изменять её. Даже если у вас её нету. Вы можете те же данные файла разбить в классы, изменить и опять конвертировать обратно. И в конце сохранить как вам удобно,

Comment: Ну вообще задумка была в том, чтобы загрузить файл по ссылке, дальше считать в бд. Файл с запросом в базу данных

Comment: Лучше сразу на сервере формировать json ответ, после используем rxjava, retrofit 2 для обработки данных на конечном устройстве.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я использовал в процессе обучение JsonArray. То есть, строка json находилась на страничке html, эта страничка указывалась, строчка загружалась и парсилась в sqlite.

Полезные ссылки:

http://java-help.ru/android-json/

http://androiddocs.ru/parsing-json-poluchaem-i-razbiraem-json-s-vneshnego-resursa/

Вот фрагмент кода:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Object... params) {


            try {
                URL url = new URL("Адрес");


                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

                resultJson = buffer.toString();
                AddData(resultJson);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: спасибо, освобожусь, обязательно посмотрю